# HTTP 200 + empty response + redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect

So I went here : http://www.surfline.com/id/?id=118055

response was `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` but it is redirecting me to http://www.surfline.com/surf-news/kilian-garland-wins-volcom-unsound-pro_118055/

So I guess it's a Javascript redirection ?

but I can't find a piece of script loaded.

It's only loading :

- http://www.surfline.com/id/?id=118055
- and http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview?id=osdim&avi=BBK405s6qVILqGoSbZNPCgKgMAKOh896VAQAAEAE4AcgBAsgDwQSgBgKoE4AB&ti=1&adk=2260143795&p=1685,348,1775,1076&tos=0,0,0,0,0&mtos=0,0,0,0,0&rs=1&ht=0&fp=client%3Dca-pub-9827052404895414%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.surfline.com%252Fsurf-news%252Fkilian-garland-wins-volcom-unsound-pro_118055%252F%26correlator%3D8792909434881%26ifk%3D1763496634%26eid%3D317150304%26oid%3D3&afp=%26output%3Dhtml%26slotname%3D3846851877%26flash%3D16.0.0%26dt%3D1420480230400%26adx%3D348%26ady%3D1684%26ifi%3D1&tdl=253&abd=1-0-26&r=u&bs=1423,839&bos=1440,900&ps=1423,1941&ss=1440,900&tt=17089&pt=431&deb=1-1-1-4-27-9&tvt=17273&iframe_loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.surfline.com%2Fsurf-news%2Fkilian-garland-wins-volcom-unsound-pro_118055%2F&is=728,90&uc=26

I'm using Chrome's Developer Tools and I can't see anything in the tab "Preview" or "Response" for these items, only response headers

So here are my two question :

- How does the server tells my browser to get the file at googlesyndication.com ?
- Can you explain me how the redirection works here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downloading the original link with wget fetches a file with this content:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/templates/article.cfm?id=118055">
```

It redirects your browser to

```
http://www.surfline.com/templates/article.cfm?id=118055
```

This URL returns a 301 redirect:

```
Location: /surf-news/kilian-garland-wins-volcom-unsound-pro_118055/
```

No JavaScript involved, just one HTML refresh and a regular HTTP redirect.

Comment: Well, I thought it would be displayed in the response tab if there were any meta-refresh. Thanks for your help

Comment: you can get the same information in chrome, you just have to enable Preserve Log in the network tab, otherwise it will start over after each redirect.

Comment: Preserve log is enabled but the response is not showing : "no response avalaible"